# Python multiprocessing class methods

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to change a class field using it's method, but when the method is put into it doesn't work.

from multiprocessing import Process

```
class Multi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 20


    def loop(self,):
        for i in range(1,100):
            self.x = i

M = Multi()

p = Process(target=M.loop)
p.start()
```

After running this program M.x is still 20. How is that possible?

Comment: Are you sure that you're checking the value *after* the process completes?

Answer (score 22):

First, you want to use `join`, which waits for the process to finish before continuing through the rest of the code.

Second, when you use `multiprocess`, it creates a new instance of `M` for every `Process`. You can see this when printing `self` within `loop`

```
class Multi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 20

    def loop(self):
        print(self, 'loop')
        for i in range(1, 100):
            self.x = i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    M = Multi()
    print(M, 'main 1')
    p = Process(target=M.loop)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(M, 'main 2')

>>> <__main__.Multi object at 0x000001E19015CCC0> main 1
>>> <__mp_main__.Multi object at 0x00000246B3614E10> loop
>>> <__main__.Multi object at 0x000001E19015CCC0> main 2
```

Because of that, the value of `x` is never updated in the original class.

Fortunately, there is a [Value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) object that you can use that handles this. This creates a shared memory object that can be modified through the processes

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value


class Multi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = Value('i', 20)

    def loop(self):
        for i in range(1, 100):
            self.x.value = i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    M = Multi()
    p = Process(target=M.loop)
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(int(M.x.value))
    >> 99
```

Comment: Thanks you very much :).

Comment: I get the exact same address in main and loop. I run this code with Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This might be because start method is 'fork' by default. If I set 'spawn' I get different addresses.