# Understanding a key difference between multiprocessing and threading in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have written a program to use threads and I create an instance of a custom object with a run(p, q) method. I pass this run() method as the target for the thread, like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def run(p, q):
        # code here

obj = MyClass()
thrd = threading.Thread(target=obj.run, args=(a, b))
```

My thread starts by executing the run() method with the passed arguments, a and b. In my case, one of them is an Event that is eventually used to stop the thread. Also, the run() method has access to all the object's instance variables, which include other objects.

As I understand it, this works because a thread shares memory with the program that creates it.

My question is how this differs with multiprocessing. e.g.

```
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=obj.run, args=(a, b))
```

I believe a process does not share memory, so am I able to do the same? How is the process able to access the whole *obj* object when it is just being given a reference to one method? Can I pass an Event? If the created process gets a copy of the whole creating program's memory, what happens with things like open database connections? How does it connect with the original Event?

And a final question (thanks for bearing with me). Is it necessary that the whole program is duplicated (with all its imported modules etc.) in a created process? What if I want a minimal process that doesn't need as much as the main program?

Happy to receive any hints at answers, or a pointer to somewhere that describes multiprocessing in this amount of detail.

Thanks so much.

Julian

Comment: Because processes don't share memory, objects have to be pickled and unpickled to be sent between processes. As long as your object is picklable it should be able to be sent between processes. But refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45312180 for more details on the specifics of values that have to cross the process boundary.

Comment: The answer you link says a new instance of the object (M in that answer, obj in my example above) is created for each Process. I don't see how that can be because how would the parameters for the constructor get specified? My question is, does my obj get copied and passed to the Process?

Answer (score 0):

each process has its own memory map! two process don't share thier memory each other. 
Inside a process thread are declared inside the memory of the process they come from. 
it doesn't, "obj.run" 's code is copied from this process to the new spawned.

Comment: I understand the code is copied, but what about the instance variables of obj? Are they copied?